# Ошибка при выводе

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуйте.

Я хочу узнать вот что: написанный код

```
var soder = document.getElemntsbyId("id");
soder.innerHtml = "text";
```

работает все нормально, но стоит в innerHtml запихнуть

```
soder.innerHtml = "<?php echo 'text' ?>";
```

то не отображается. Как это исправить? Или как правильнее написать код, чтобы браузер читал РНР код.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что там теги, и броузер не отображает их.

Кстати, в getElemnt**s**byId у вас опечатка.

```
var soder = document.getElemntbyId("id");
var php_text = document.createTextNode('<?php echo "text";?>');
soder.appendChild(php_text);
```

По идее должно работать.

Comment: Не работает. (((

Comment: Конечно не работает, потому что в той же злонещастной функции всё еще опечатка.

getElementbyId

а не 

getElemntbyId


Вот пример: http://pastehtml.com/view/b1ybh3rjy.html

Comment: Нет, с синтаксисом все ок, потому что я пишу на dreamweaver, а там в яваскрипте стоит набрать тоску после переменной, автоматом выходит список атрибутов и я выбираю оттуда.

Answer (score 1):

А какой код вы ожидаете увидеть? Браузер воспринимает все что находится в <> как html теги и поскольку тега <?php echo 'text' ?> он не знает просто пропускает его и ничего не показывает, естественно обрабатывать пхп код он не собирается. Если вы хотите просто вывести код как текст, то нужно написать так

`&lt;?php echo 'text' ?&gt;`

А если хотите вывести слово text с помощью пхп, то это можно сделать только на сервере.

Comment: Либо добавьте точку с запятой после 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

Может ошибка в самом PHP коде, или попробуйте засунуть код PHP в переменную как просто текст и потом значение переменной уже выводить в innerHTML (может JS вырезает какие-то символы или интерпретирует их по своему).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php text ?>
```

Что Вы этим сказать-то хотели ? ) Вообще, это должно давать php - ошибку, если только у Вас нет константы text.
Правильно:

```
<?php echo "text";?>
```

Comment: Гы, я вообще подумал что text у автора подразумевается как огромный кусок кода там.

Comment: ну я прость второпях недописал echo ))) на самом деле echo "text"  просто пример отображения РНР кода на деле мне нужно вот что
var soder = document.getElemntsbyId("id")
soder.innerHtml = "<? php category ($cat_number)?>"
и что самое прикольненкое в исходном коде страницы РНР функция category и все записи из бд по категории $cat_number видны но на самой страничке нет ничего в Firefox в консоли ошибок пишется missing;before statement

Comment: Так может тогда поискать эту потерянную точку с запятой в JS ? )

Comment: так без Jquery то есть просто вывести эту функцию выводится же

Comment: Приведите кусок javascript, который в итоге получается в исходном коде страницы и не работает, а то вслепую сложно понять, что именно не так

Answer (score 0):

```
var soder = document.getElemntsbyId("id") soder.innerHtml = "<? php echo htmlspecialchars(category ($cat_number));?>"
```

Comment: вот просто интересно, и что это выйдет? 

Вы проверяли перед тем как советовать ?

Comment: вряд ли сработает но спасибо все же попробую

Comment: спасибо все же попробовал и не работает 
но зато работает Jquery )))
он выводит по клику название категории то бишь нажал пункт1 выводится ПУНКТ 1  нажал пункт2 ПУНКТ 2 а все записи из бд которые выводятся по умолчанию стираются 
код такой 
$('#id').click (function ()
{var text = $(this).text();
$('id-2').html (text)}
)
если засунуть это в XMLHttpRequest
в событие onreadystatechange 
код исполняется но как вместо переменной text выполнить РНР функцию без использования json или XML нет никаких идей

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотели от этой записи? Вам как браузер будет выполнять функции PHP в html документе?

Comment: а как браузер выводит их без Jquery или javascript?
вы наверно не поняли что я хочу сделать 
обьясняю развернуто
у меня есть 2 меню гориз.и верт.
1-ое работает с перезагрузкой при помощи GET и switch case
а второе нет потому что я не хочу перезагружать и адресная строка уже содержит GET который я уже не могу менять понимаете?
и мне теперь нужно сделать это левое меню так же как и верхнее то есть нажимаю по названию и появляются именно те записи которые нужны
хотя я уже сделал это используя XML и Ajax но там пришлось юзать wsdl и если бы нашлось бы  простое решение был бы премного благодарен